# array_push() is not pushing a loop values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the following code:-

```
@php $options = [];  @endphp
@foreach($question->answers as $answer)

    @switch($question->type)
    @case('multi-select')

    @php
    array_push($options, $answer->content);
    var_dump($answer->content);
    @endphp

    @break
    @endswitch

@endforeach

{{var_dump($options)}}
```

I am trying to push an foreach loop values into options[] array, but the result of {{var_dump($options)}} code at the end line is:-

> array(0) { }

The value of above var_dump($answer->content) code is :-

> string(10) "Preservar" string(12) "Emotional" string(12) "Fiction"
>   string(12) "Sequence" string(12) "Analytical" string(14)
>   "constructional"

Comment: What is the `$question->type`? Are you sure it's `multi-select`?

Comment: @aynber Yes sure, you can see that the var_dump($answer->content)  is returning a values

Comment: just noting that you would save the overhead of calling a function when using $options[] =$answer->content - it is a lot faster

Comment: I want to use $options[] array inside the @foreach loop not outside , but i putted it outside just for testing.

Comment: is `$answer->content` type array?

Comment: add var_dump($question->type)